# Unity, посмотреть туда, куда смотрит камера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт для оружия.
Мы пускаем рейкаст, и когда попадаем им, смотрим на точку попадения.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(camPos, camForward, out _hit, 10000, aimingMask))
{
  weaponTransform.LookAt(_hit);
}
```

Но что делать, если мы не попали? Как заставить оружие смотреть в ту же сторону, например, как если бы мы попали на расстоянии 100?

```
hit = camForward * 100;
weaponTransform.LookAt(_hit);
```

Данный код заставляет смотреть оружие куда то в сторону. Но точно не туда куда попал бы луч на расстоянии 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camPos + camForward * 100` вместо `camForward * 100`